# Problema de atributos en POO

Tags: python-3.x

Quiero que me halle el vector entre dos puntos, pero cuando voy a hallarlo me dice que la X y la y no son atributos de la funcion "segundo_punto" y tambien de la funcion "primer_punto", cabe aclarar que el vector se halla restando la x de ambos puntos y la y de ambos puntos

```
import math

class Puntos():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def __str__(self):
        return "{},{}".format(self.x,self.y)

    def cuadrante(self):
        if self.x>0 and self.y>0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 1")
        elif self.x<0 and self.y>0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 2")
        elif self.x<0 and self.y<0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 3")
        elif self.x>0 and self.y<0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 4")
        else:
            print("El punto esta sobre el origen")

    def segundo_punto(self):
        self.x=input("\nDigite la X del segundo punto: ")
        self.y=input("Digite la y del segundo punto: ")

        return "{},{}".format(self.x,self.y)

    def vector(self):
        primer_punto=self.__str__()  #Almaceno el primer punto en la variable
        segundo_punto=self.segundo_punto()  #Almaceno el segundo punto en la variable 
        operacion_vector=(self.segundo_punto.x-self.primer_punto.x , self.segundo_punto.y-self.primer_punto.y) #Esta es la linea que me arroja el error
        return operacion_vector

def main():

    x=input("Digite la x del primer punto: ")
    y=input("Digite la y del primer punto: ")
    puntos=Puntos(x,y)


    print(puntos.vector())   

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código es bastante confuso, pero parece que tiene propósitos académicos, para ver cómo se relacionan funciones, métodos y atributos.

Hay varios errores lógicos y de sintaxis. No necesitas el módulos `math` porque no lo estás usando. Si estás dentro de una clase, los métodos y atributos son válidos dentro de toda la clase, se reconocen porque empiezan con `self.algo`. Cualquier variable definida dentro de un método (como `operacion_vector`) tienen el mismo comportamiento que una función, solo valen dentro de ese método, para poder ser usado en otro lugar tiene que ser retornado.

Para que al menos funcione el código, se puede escribir de la siguiente forma

```
class Puntos():
    def __init__(self, x1, y1):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1

    def cuadrante(self):
        if self.x>0 and self.y>0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 1")
        elif self.x<0 and self.y>0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 2")
        elif self.x<0 and self.y<0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 3")
        elif self.x>0 and self.y<0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 4")
        else:
            print("El punto esta sobre el origen")

    def segundo_punto(self):
        self.x2 = int(input("\nDigite la X del segundo punto: "))
        self.y2 = int(input("Digite la y del segundo punto: "))
        return "{},{}".format(self.x2, self.y2)

    def vector(self):
        print("El primer punto es {},{}".format(self.x1, self.y1))
        self.segundo_punto() # Definir segundo punto
        print("El segundo punto es {},{}".format(self.x2, self.y2))
        self.x = self.x2-self.x1
        self.y = self.y2-self.y1
        print()
        operacion_vector = "El punto resultante es {},{}".format(self.x, self.y)
        self.cuadrante()
        return operacion_vector

def main():
    x1 = int(input("Digite la x del primer punto: "))
    y1 = int(input("Digite la y del primer punto: "))
    puntos = Puntos(x1, y1) # Instanciar la clase con el primer punto
    print(puntos.vector()) 

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

El mismo código, un poco más ordenado, pero más alterado, sería algo como

```
class Puntos():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def cuadrante(self):
        if self.x>0 and self.y>0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 1")
        elif self.x<0 and self.y>0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 2")
        elif self.x<0 and self.y<0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 3")
        elif self.x>0 and self.y<0:
            print("El punto se encuentra en el cuadrante 4")
        else:
            print("El punto esta sobre el origen")

    def realizar_operacion(self, p1, p2):
        self.x = p2[0] - p1[0]
        self.y = p2[1] - p1[1]

    def definir_punto(self, num_punto):
        x = int(input("\nDigite la x del {} punto: ".format(num_punto)))
        y = int(input("Digite la y del {} punto: ".format(num_punto)))
        print("El {} punto es {}, {}".format(num_punto, x, y))
        return([x, y])

def main():
    puntos = Puntos()
    p1 = puntos.definir_punto('primer')
    p2 = puntos.definir_punto('segundo')
    puntos.realizar_operacion(p1, p2) # realizar el calculo
    print("\nEl punto resultante es {}, {}".format(puntos.x, puntos.y))
    puntos.cuadrante() # metodo para imprimir el cuadrante

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

[NOTA] En ambos códigos cuando el resultado está sobre un eje (ej 13, 0) indica que "El punto está sobre el origen".